# How do I use a Property defined in a wixproj file inside a component

Tags: installation, wix, windows-installer

I have declared a property inside a `PropertyGroup` in a `wixproj` file.

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <Permit>false</Permit>
</PropertyGroup>
```

I use this property as a `Condition` to run several commands `BeforeBuild` and `AfterBuild`

```
<Exec Condition=" '$(Permit)' == 'true' " Command="--command here--" />
```

In my `Product.wxs` file, I have defined some components that I want to include or exclude based on the defined `Permit` property.

```
<ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents">

    <ComponentRef Id="SomeComponent"/>

    <!--Component to add based on the property-->
    <?if $(Permit)=true ?>
        <ComponentRef Id="PermissionComponent"/>
    <?endif?>
</ComponentGroup>

Anytime I build the project, I get this error.
```

> Ill-formed preprocessor variable '$(Permit)'.  Variables must have a
> prefix (like 'var.', 'env.', or 'sys.') and a name at least 1
> character long. If the literal string '$(Cache)' is desired, use
> '$$(Cache)'.

I have already tried all the specified prefix but it still doesn't work.
Is there something I am not doing right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add your variable to `<DefineConstants>` wix setting in the `wixproj` file. Like this (there may be already other constants defined, you probably want to keep those. Also watch out for configurations, you may need to add it for release/debug/etc):

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <Permit>false</Permit>
</PropertyGroup>
...
<DefineConstants>Debug;Permit=$(Permit)</DefineConstants>
```

And then just use:

```
<?if $(var.Permit)=true ?>
```